# What musical term does this refer to?

Tags: word, rebus, music

What musical term does this refer to:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.........

Clue for help:

> Maybe I should write that as: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O O O O O O O O O O O O . . . . . . . . .

Comment: are there definite number of 'O' s after N.....seems like cassette blocked ?

Comment: Cassette blocked is a great point. It continues with O forever.

Comment: I fear your gramophone record has a scratch on the recitation of the alphabet. How distressing!

Comment: I will be adding the exact expected answer to all my puzzles, so that the clues are explained, but if somebody else has got the correct answer, then that will be the "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would say the answer is

> Staccato

Because it sounds like

> 'Stuck at O'

Comment: Correct !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be

> A music-disc that went in loop. It was spelling the alphabet, when suddenly something went wrong!

Otherwise it may be

> A [loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(music)) preceded by a [scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(music)). The scale is made with the notes from A to N (A to G notes are the standard ones, H to N may be the next octave).

Comment: First attempt is on the right track, but there is a specific musical term, because it went wrong at the specific letter. Also look at the clue given in the question. Second attempt is not on track.

Comment: So this is a rebus?

Answer (score 1):

So "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO........." looks like it is

> stuck at the letter O.

Now, the clue says that it is better to write that as "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O O O O O O O O O O O O . . . . . . . . ." which is

> marked by or composed of disconnected parts or sounds.

Hence the musical term, as per Definition, is :

> Staccato